# Trying to download to csv javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript

In the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/PooLpQr?editors=1010) I am trying to create a function to download the array of objects to csv. Currently I get the error "row.join is not a function". How can I go about creating a function to allow the download of the data to csv? Thank you.

JS

```
$scope.download_csv = function() {
  console.log();
    var csv = 'ID,Date,Description,Status\n';
    $scope.ticketsA.forEach(function(row) {
            csv += row.join(',');
            csv += "\n";
    });

  console.log(csv);
}
```

Comment: What is a simple example of `$scope.ticketsA`? so we can know what a `row` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.join()` is a method used for arrays, instead you are trying to use it on an object.
You need to add each key's value manually.

```
csv += row.ID + ",";
csv += "\"" + row.Date + "\",";
csv += "\"" + row.Description + "\",";
csv += "\"" + row.Status + "\"";
csv += "\n";
```